# Implementing grid hierarchy (parent row has many child rows) in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, ng-grid

I want to implement grid hierarchy (parent row has many child rows). Please refer to the link for reference - http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy. How can it be implemented using Angularjs, ngGrid in asp.net web api project?

Answer (score 0):

If you use ui-grid (the 3.0 version of ngGrid), then this is the expandable feature: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/306_expandable_grid

Expandable still has some gremlins in it, so you'll get some compromises and work arounds (or alternatively maybe need to submit some fixes), but it is the same concept.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'll give this a try and post in the same thread.

Comment: I tried using ui-grid expandable grid, here we get the parent child relationship but the nice paging of ng-grid is not supported, instead we have infinite scrolling feature. It would have been good to have the paging feature as well...

Comment: I tried  ui grid expandable - http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/306_expandable_grid , along with server side paging, sorting and filtering. It works very well. Thanks again for help

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Angular Grid](http://www.angulargrid.com). The interface is similar to ng-grid. There is a ['test drive'](http://www.angulargrid.com/example.html) section to see it demonstrated, where you can group by a column, giving a parent / child rows layout.

Comment: I want my grid like  http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy. The Angular grid is achieving through grouping. I want kind of nested table.